# jQuery select a class only if it is contained in another class

Tags: jquery

For example... say I was wanting to find elements of class 'A' that were contained within a div of class 'John'

```
<div class='Abe'>
    <input class='A'>
    <input class='A'>
</div>

<div class='John'>
    <input class='A'>
    <input class='A'>
</div>
```

How could I just select the two class A objects within the John div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply:

```
var elements = $('div.John .A');
//                |  |    || 
//                |  |    |^__ match elements with class A (the period is the class selector)
//                |  |    ^ __ the space is the descendant selector (the right side must be a descendant of the left side)
//                |  ^ _______ class selector for John
//                ^ __________ the matched elements with class John must be div type elements
```

The space in the selector means it will match any element with class `A` that is a descendant of div elements with class `John`.

[W3 docs for Descendant Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors).

Comment: + 1 and for OP could play around with http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/ `hasClass` idea as well, `:)`

Comment: You won the race with `3Secs` ;-)

Comment: Sorry for asking such an apparently obvious question :P jQuery makes things so easy!

Answer (score 2):

Try the `SELECTOR` like

```
$('.John .A');
```

First It will select the `John` classed `div` and then it will select the elements with class `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Well...

```
$('.John > .A');
```

or if you want it the other way around

```
$('.A').filter(function(i, el){
    return $(el).closest('.John').length;
});
```